# Convert a list into a bonary presence/absence matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of character vectors:

```
set.seed(1)
sets.list <- list(s1 = paste0("id",sample(1:10,3,replace=F)),
                  s2 = paste0("id",sample(1:10,4,replace=F)),
                  s3 = paste0("id",sample(1:10,4,replace=F)))
```

And I would like to create an `integer` `matrix` where the columns are the unique values across the `sets.list` (`sets.ids <- unique(unlist(sets.list))`), the rows are the `sets.list` elements, and the values are binary indicators of whether a value is a member of the `sets.list` element (1) or not (0).

This is how I'm currently generating this `matrix`:

```
sets.mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(sets.list, function(s){
  set.row <- rep(0,length(sets.ids))
  set.row[which(sets.ids %in% s)] <- 1
  return(set.row)
}))

colnames(sets.mat) <- sets.ids
```

My question is if there's anything that is more concise in terms of code (perhaps something using `tidyverse`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
as.matrix(mtabulate(sets.list))
```

---

Or `stack` it to a two column data.frame and then with `table` from `base R`

```
+(table(stack(sets.list)[2:1]) > 0)
#  values
#ind  id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id7 id9
#  s1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
#  s2   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
#  s3   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: I'd add  `%>% data.matrix()` to the `mtabulate` option so that it returns a `matrix`

Answer (score 1):

We count occurrence of each list element in `sets.list` using `table` after converting them to `factor` with `levels` as `sets.ids`.

```
t(sapply(sets.list, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = sets.ids))))

#   id9 id4 id7 id1 id2 id5 id3
#s1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
#s2   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
#s3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
```